# How to use Android Volley for parallel calling

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to use Android-Volley project for network operations of my project.

and I like the implementation of [this](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/) and I use it in my project.

I have activity that list users and their feeds. User list in my Activity and Their Feeds in Fragment and I can't get response of my request in Fragment and I get this log message.

> W/SingleClientConnManager﹕ Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager:
>   connection still allocated.
>       Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.

I think that it is because of my using type Volley and I have changed creation of RequestQueue

Log Message Version:

```
if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // We need this in order to access the cookie store
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // create the request queue
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new HttpClientStack(mHttpClient));
        }
```

Changed Version:

```
if (mRequestQueue == null) {

            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        }
```

With this change, I cant get response...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new HttpClientStack(client));
```

As a result of this, we lose one of Volley’s greatest features, which is making multiple requests at once.  This is due to the fact that we are including an HttpClient and we have to live by its rules and let one connection close before we introduce another one. See full explanation: http://captechconsulting.com/blog/clinton-teegarden/android-volley-library-tutorial - Session **Cookies**

try this:

```
if ( this.mRequestQueue == null ) {

        DefaultHttpClient mDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        final ClientConnectionManager mClientConnectionManager = mDefaultHttpClient.getConnectionManager();
        final HttpParams mHttpParams = mDefaultHttpClient.getParams();
        final ThreadSafeClientConnManager mThreadSafeClientConnManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager( mHttpParams, mClientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry() );

        mDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient( mThreadSafeClientConnManager, mHttpParams );

        final HttpStack httpStack = new HttpClientStack( mDefaultHttpClient );

        this.mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue( this.getApplicationContext(), httpStack );
}
```

Comment: The link is broken. :(

Comment: @PuruPawar, Sorry about it, could you try to use Retrofit, because is a best Android Http library available at the moment. Much more content about how to use, we can combinate Retrofit + RxJava and solve most thread issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am well aware of Retrofit's upper hand on Volley. But the fact that Volley is owned by Google itself, I am more keen to stick with it. Also, Volley is still faster(~50-75%) than the good old AsyncTasks and that's good enough speed for me.